# Azure Credit Balance

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

I'm new to Azure API's and am trying to create a simple interface to grab the remaining credits on a handful of azure accounts that I manage.  I started doing this using vbs as that's the only language I'm really familiar with.  I ran into several issues with login pages and someone recommended using the Azure API.

I've wandered into an area I'm wholly unfamiliar with.  From what I'm reading it's a relatively new interface as is and most people are unfamiliar with it. I've used the following sample:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/billing-dotnet-usage-api/

To be able to log into the account but from there I'm stuck really.  The code provided just returns an empty "value[]" as a result.

I'm sort of at a loss.  I'm reading through the azure API resources on MSDN but most pages referencing credits are just telling you what you can spend credits on.

I've started browsing:

https://github.com/Azure

Hoping to find something there but so far have turned up little in terms of just grabbing credits remaining.

I hope I'm making sense.  I hope I'm not overthinking this and someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: `To be able to log into the account but from there I'm stuck really. The code provided just returns an empty "value[]" as a result.` - Please make sure you are providing correct parameters especially start/end dates. I saw similar thing on another question here just a few days ago.

Answer (score 3):

You can visit https://www.microsoftazuresponsorships.com/Balance to check balance for `azure for students` subscription

Answer (score 0):

You can find some samples of the Billing Rest API here:

[Get consumption data for an Azure subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219001)

Answer (score 0):

To see the balance and bills of Azure 
1) Go to the Right top corner where your profile/icon/email is displayed.
2) Click on the icon and select "View My Bill"

From here you can get more information and Subscription wise details.